# How can I download the latest dataset(.csv) with an automatic Python script from Nasdaq?

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset

I want to download a .csv file from here automatically, every time I run the script:
https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/quotes/historical

So whenever I open the notebook I will get the latest data from Nasdaq, if I run the correct script, I don't have to upload the dataset manually.

This is the URL of the download:
https://www.nasdaq.com/api/v1/historical/AMZN/stocks/2010-10-26/2020-10-26

I tried some libraries, but none of them worked for me.
I use google colaboratory and Python3.

Comment: I forget that I ask for working or well-tried codes or libraries with this site(nasdaq).

Comment: What have you tried and in what way did they not work for you?

Comment: @kabdulla I wrote what I have been already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a reason which I don't understand (maybe someone here who knows more can let us both know), you need to provide headers along with your request. I got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60184579/4988601).

So in your case the following seems to work for me:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/api/v1/historical/AMZN/stocks/2010-10-26/2020-10-26'
headers = { "user-agent":"Mozilla"} 

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

open('HistoricalQuotes_2020_10_26.csv', 'wb').write(r.content)
```